# detect a sim card change using alarm manager

Tags: android

I am developing an android app to detect a SIM change in the device on clicking a button. I want the app to execute the `checksimstate()` method every 5 minutes using alarm manager. I am using `getSimSerialNumber()` and `getSubscriberId()` to detect old sim and new sim.

Where should I call the method `checksimstate()` so that it gets executed every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to check for sim state every 5 minutes. instead you can listen to `ACTION_SIM_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast receiver and write your code to detect sim changed or not.